# How to set up and use EC2 CLI on Mac?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am stuck at using Amazon EC2 CLI.

- I have downloaded the Command Line Tools from
  `http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351`.
- I placed the `bin` and `lib` folder into my Amazon project folder: `/Users/Invictus/EC2`
- I downloaded the `cert-xxxx.pem` and `pk-xxx.pem` into the same folder.
- Created a `.bash_profile` in the same folder.
- I tried to execute `ec2-describe-images -o amazon` after I moved to `cd /Users/Invictus/EC2`.
- The system does not recognise the command: `command not found`.
- If I try to execute the same command inside the `bin` folder, the result is the same.

My `.bash_profile`:

```
export EC2_HOME=~/.EC2
export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=`ls $EC2_HOME/pk-*.pem`
export EC2_CERT=`ls $EC2_HOME/cert-*.pem`
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/
```

Where did I make a mistake?

My aim is to connect to the launched instance and be able to execute commands there from my local machine.

I have Java installed.

Answer (score 1):

The newer [AWS Unified CLI Tools](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) is much, *much* easier to set up. All you need is Python, which comes built-in to every Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things I can think of:

1. Your .bash_profile should be in /Users/Invictus/ , *not* /Users/Invictus/EC2. Move it to your home directory and log off and log back in (or restart your machine) and see if it picks up the right path.
2. Instead of ec2-describe-images, can you run it as "./ec2-describe-images" - does that work? If not, can you check the permissions on that script?